# Python Socket error number 3 on server side

Tags: python, linux, sockets, centos

While programming the server side socket python script I am getting socket error number 3 and my server's bind method is not executed. here is my code. Is there any error in this code?[image]

When I execute this program, it shows following error:
Bind failed. -3 Message Temporary failure in name resolution.
I am using linux centOS 6.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing

```
myhost=socket.gethostname();
```

to

```
myhost="127.0.0.1";
```

Or simply modify the file under "/etc/hosts" and give a hostname with related IP.
such as following.

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
192.168.0.5 youranotherserver1
192.168.0.30 youranotherserver2
```